# Word Stress in "It's up to you"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I watched a video on Youtube about the pronunciation of the phrase "It's up to you": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaZrkhCqWbk and it says that "up" is the stressed word.

I think that "It's" can be reduce to "ts" in fast speech. I noticed this in American movie especially with phrases such as "It's okay" (pronounced as: tsokay).

I would like to know if we need any stress on the last word the pronoun "you" or not? The video doesn't mention anything about the word "you" for me it seems that it doesn't require stress in a normal conversation.

Any suggestion appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, if a native speaker is going to "reduce" the initial vowel, they'll almost always discard the /t/ as well, giving something like **SUP CHEW** (or *"S'ok"*, which is a common "eye dialect" form for that one).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You know, that’s one of those cases where I never affricate (maybe it chewy). I’m not sure that I’ve ever heard it done, either.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree with tchrist here, but this may be a difference between AmE and BrE.

Comment: @tchrist: So it your case I guess it would be **sup t'you** - or would you also articulate the initial /t/ and say **t'sup t'you**? That would seem somewhat odd to me (but in the land of the free, *anything* is possible! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Dunno if I say the first *t*, but I do say the second one.

Comment: @tchrist: Don't tell me you're one of those people who [believe they] naturally articulate ***prince*** and ***prints*** differently! Personally, I'm not convinced *anyone* does, but the truth is I doubt very much that I could *hear* any such distinction even if an oscilloscope proved it was present (and that other people could in fact hear the difference).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Don’t be silly.  However, there is no *t* in the previous sentence. :)

Comment: @tchrist: We Brits like ***tea***, but we're not so keen on ***/t/*** (it was to get rid of the latter that we invented the gloʔal stop! :)

Comment: In non-formal situations, two-nahalf syllabic nuclei, both stressed; intonation varies with shades of meaning: /'səptə'yu/.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the shade of meaning that you want to deliver.

"It's *up to you*" indicates that it is your decision to make or action to take.

"It's up to *you*", on the other hand, means that the person or people being addressed are the only ones who can decide or act in this case.